# micro SD card reader overheating

Tags: sd-card, overheating, card-reader

I recently purchased this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001164055136.html, a tiny USB C micro SD card reader. When I was moving gigabytes worth of data, tby the end of it, this reader was heating up. Should I  be alarmed by this? Maybe it's a indication the micro SD is being overdriven or something?

Comment: Why do you say "over"? Have you noticed any problem with it? Because if not then it's within acceptable parameters. And the heat you far more likely to happen in the USB port, not from the adapter.

Comment: I’ve tried it directly on the USB C port of my laptop & the USB 3.0 port (with a USB A to USB C dongle). Got hot on both. With the second one, only the micro SD reader got hot; the dongle didn’t. Seeing the dongle in between didn’t get hot, it couldn’t be the USB 3.0 port either.

Comment: The card itself also produces heat, particularly when writing. At $US1, you might just use it until it fails. Also, how "hot" is *hot*? Some temperature rise is expected, you'd need to measure it, whether with IR thermometer or thermocouple, to get a useful answer.